# estimated time for application to appear in play store?

Tags: android, publishing

I know that this topic would have been discussed here a lot of times, but I couldn't find a proper answer for my query even after searching a lot across the internet. Therefore I thought I should ask a question here so as to get the answer from the developer here who may have published there app in play store. The point which is more confusing is that the status
of my application shows **PUBLISHED** but when I search in the play store I don't find my application. Can anyone pls tell me that how long it will take before the app to finally appear in the play store.

[image]

Comment: Probably stupid question, but if you are searching for it from your android device, does your application support it?

Comment: @Daniel what's off topic in that? and did u down vote the post?

Comment: @Lope i searched from my device as well as from the computer and yes my device support the app. so its better if you dont try to be too smart

Comment: @Daniel search this topic.. there are lot of same type of question on here already

Comment: I did not mean no disrespect. I just pointed out something that people might miss in some cases. I learned that there is no such thing as too obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application get displayed in play store within a short time after you publish. It takes maximum of 1 day time to display and not more than that. I hope there was mistake from your end only. Better you check whether any errors exists by clicking on the Errors hyperlink. If still no hints then you have to check for something else.

Comment: I clicked on the error hyperlink to check for the errors but there were no error. ** If still no hints then you have to check for something else.** <---- what did you mean by this?

Comment: I mean you may done some mistakes in signing the app

Comment: i have signed the apps properly, i am sure about that.. what else could be the problem?

Comment: Hey, I am not sure but it looks like you have done mistake while uploading the app. App is not shown to everyone if it was selected to publish on single country. By mistake you might done that, let you verify that again. This is one chance app is not shown while you search from india but uploaded in US Country. Not sure but it might help you.